# Black empty area below table in iOS7 with nested UIViewControllers

Tags: ios

I get some black empty area below a UITableViewController when nested in a certain way (iOS7). Would anybody know why that happens?

(obviously the code is a 100% stripped down version of the actual app's code)

```
    - (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *) launchOptions {
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [UITabBarController new];
    UITableViewController *demoViewController = [UITableViewController new];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:demoViewController];

    tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
    navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    // THESE LINES INTRODUCE A BLACK AREA BELOW THE TABLE
    InBetweenViewController *inBetweenViewController = [InBetweenViewController new];
    [inBetweenViewController addChildViewController:navigationController];
    [inBetweenViewController.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = @[ inBetweenViewController ];

    // INSTEAD, THIS LINE WORKS CORRECTLY
    /* tabBarController.viewControllers = @[ navigationController ]; */

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@implementation InBetweenViewController
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
        subview.frame = self.view.bounds;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `inBetweenViewController` doesn't know how to render its `childViewController`. You just add the the view of that controller without any further instructions. It should be possible to solve this by using a simple `autoresizingMask`. You then also need to make sure that the subview's size is the same as the superview's size when you add it. If you need more details on how to do that, let me know.

Comment: Good point. But in the original code the `inBetweenViewController` actually sets the frame.

Comment: ... But it still behaves like the original code. What I see is that the `navigationController` is layouting its subview (`demoViewController`) with reduced height. Interesting to know is that the black 'gap' is exactly the height of the tab bar below.